# How to create a web push notification using Flask

Tags: python, flask, redis, push-notification

I'm trying to implement a web push notification in my project. Using some tutorials   I got create an alert on index page when I post a message. But it's far from being what I want.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing...</h1>
</body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source = new EventSource('/stream');
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
    alert(event.data);
    };
</script>
</html>
```

post.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Posting a Message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{url_for('post')}}" method='post'>
        Message: <input type="text" name="message" size='50'> <input type="submit" value="Launch!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, Response
from redis import Redis
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'asdf'
red = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

def event_stream():
    pubsub = red.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe('notification')
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        print message
        yield 'data: %s\n\n' % message['data']


@app.route('/post', methods=['POST','GET'])
def post():
 if request.method=="POST":
    message = request.form['message']
    now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).time()
    red.publish('notification', u'[%s] %s: %s' % (now.isoformat(), 'Aviso', message))
 return render_template('post.html')


@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return Response(event_stream(),
                          mimetype="text/event-stream")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8001, debug=True,threaded=True)
```

Well, I would like to implement a subscribe system, I think that is how is called. The user allow to receive notification from the website and when he clicks on the "news" it opens a new page with the detailed content.

The index page does not need to be opened for receving the message.

Comment: What is exactly the question/problem? What you did seems to work. Even if your EventSource object may not point to the right URL endpoints, the hostname should be needed.

Comment: I think where I reached is not the push notification what I want. About the url you mean {{url_for(stream)}} like that?

Comment: Your URL in your javascript should look like http://hostname/stream or something like that. That can explain why you don't reach your notifications.

Comment: hmmm.. Where would be be my "hostname"? I don't know, but I can reach the "notification", it appears in alert way, only if the index page is open.

Comment: If you run in local then, it would be http://localhost:<your_port_number>/stream. The default port of Flask is 5000.